# C++ #include error

Tags: c++

I have two files `functions.h` and `functions.cpp`.  The first has declarations of various functions and the latter has definitions.  At the top of `functions.cpp` I have the statement:

```
#include "functions.h"
```

my compiler tells me I need a semicolon after this, but I don't.  What is wrong?

Comment: Show the rest of the file if you can... because without it.. it's tough to tell.

Comment: Sounds like you need a semicolon at the end of the header file. Maybe after a class declaration? But yeah, need the rest of the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem usually is generated  when you declare class in function.h forgetting add semicolon in class last block; 
eg:

```
class Test {
```

}

right answer

```
class Test {
```

};

Answer (score 1):

**One possible suggestion** is Check your `Functions.h` for `Error`.